# Preferable way to dynamically call some object's method

Tags: python, object, methods, dynamic

What is more preferable way to dynamically call some object's method:

```
method = getattr(object, name)
method(*args, **kw)
```

Or

```
import operator
method = operator.methodcaller(name)
method(object, *args, **kw)
```

Comment: `getattr` is what I would suggest, no extra imports and I've yet to see operator used for this purpose in practice.

Comment: I always use `getattr` for this purpose, too.

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I am struggling to come up with a half-decent argument either way...

Comment: I would use getattr, but I will check if method is callable before calling it.

Comment: @spicavigo if you'll use `operator.methodcaller` there are no needs checking if method is callable

Comment: `operator.methodcaller()` is more explicit. Just saying...

Comment: It's an extra import of a lot of extra stuff, also makes the program not pure python as these are c implementations may be good for performance but negligible in this scenario. Instead of checking if its callable however just wrap it in a try its faster than an if.