# Creating a list of methods to be executed in Python

Tags: python, methods, iteration

How can I create a list of methods in python to be applied to an object?

Given some arbitrary class:

```
class someClass:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.size = s

    def shrink(self):
        self.size -= 1

    def grow(self):
        self.size += 1

    def invert(self):
        self.size = -self.size
```

I want to be able to write an iterable object like this list:

```
instructions = [shrink, grow, shrink, shrink, grow, invert]
```

To be run through a for-loop later:

```
elephant = someClass(90)
sizeList = []
for ins in instructions:
    elephant.ins()
    sizeList.append(elephant.size)
```

I've done something similar with functions before. Not being able to do this with methods would require me to rewrite an intimidating amount of code...

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821423/preferable-way-to-dynamically-call-some-objects-method

Comment: you can also use `someClass.__dict__[ins](elephant)`, otherwise `getattr()` is good.

Comment: @Ashwini Looking at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__dict__#special-attributes), `.__dict__` is an implementation detail. Why would you ever use it instead of `getattr()` anyway?

Answer (score 6):

You could create a list of the method *names* then use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to access the methods:

```
instructions = ["shrink", "grow", "shrink"]
for i in instructions:
     getattr(elephant, i)()
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using strings for your list of instructions, you could do the following:

```
instructions = [someClass.shrink, someClass.grow, someClass.shrink,
                someClass.shrink, someClass.grow, someClass.invert]
elephant = someClass(90)
sizeList = []
for ins in instructions:
    ins(elephant)
    sizeList.append(elephant.size)
```

Comment: +1, for showing that you can call a method as if it is a function by passing the instance as a parameter; in this case elephant instance will be passed as the self parameter to the method (function)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly naïvely:

```
for ins in instructions:
  getattr(elephant, ins)()
```

Gotchas include that `ins` must be a string and that it's probably wise to validate both that `ins` is what you really want to call and that `getattr(elephant, ins)` is a callable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dir`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) to get all property names of an object, and [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) to get a property value of an object. You may also want to not call any non-[callable](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#callable) properties (such as `2` or `"foo"`):

```
for m in dir(elephant):
    if not m.startswith('_'):
        f = getattr(elephant, m)
        if callable(f): # Do not try to call non-function properties
            f()
```

Comment: You might want to integrate [callable()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#callable)